# Is there a reference table which shows which mysql versions are supported by which rails versions?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, version

Where should I be looking to find which rails versions support which mysql versions?

Comment: Rails doesn't access MySQL directly, rather it uses an adapter. Rails 3 uses the [`mysql2`](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) gem, which doesn't specify any version requirements.

Comment: @gg_s you are absolutely right, I should have phrased my question better.  I'm trying to decide whether to move from mysql5.1 to mysql5.5 or even later.  What I don't know is whether the msyql2 gem will support later versions.  That's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: the easiest way is just to install mysql v5.5 or whatever and run tests (or check it manually if there are no tests)

Comment: @trushkevich Yes I was starting to head that way in my thinking.  Just surprised that Rails with its otherwise excellent documentation lacks this.

Comment: too small limit for chars number in comment ) posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it should be in Rails documentation. The reason is that communication with DB is handled via adapters and is not in core rails functionality, so it is a matter of compatibility between rails and some particular adapter (mysql or mysql2 for example for MySQL) rather than between rails and some particular DBMS. Adapter is a 3rd party product, so how the rails team can be responsible for it? You should find out 2 things - 1) which adapter works for MySQL 5.5 and 2) with which rails versions that adapter can be used. In any case you should focus on adapter, not on rails if you want to use some particular DBMS.

Comment: Yes I agree this is not a Rails documentation issue. Please see my comment above to gg_s

Answer (score 0):

Rails can use several different kinds of databases, and this sort of interoperability precludes use of advanced features. As such, Rails seems to rely on basic functionality which all but prehistoric versions of MySQL can provide.

This might have something to do with the Rails tenet of convention over configuration. You are given a basic set of database functions to use, none of which are cutting-edge.

This might also explain the apparent nonexistence of such a compatibility list. I have yet to find one.

Comment: I've looked at the mysql2 adaptor info on git but it doesn't seem to answer the question on versions supported.  I'll ask the question there.  The reason I'm surprised by the lack of documentation on this topic is because Rails and MySQL are used almost everywhere in production and therefore I was expecting someone to have come up with this info.  Also since mysql2 is the 'standard' adaptor for rails I was expecting 'SOME' info in Rails as well.  Ah well I'll continue looking.  Thanks for your comments.